# facet plots with different yaxis scales

Tags: r, ggplot2

Plot with multiple facets which have different scales.  Simple example:

```
require(data.table)
require(ggplot2)

nr <- 10000
inp.dt <- rbind(
    data.table(type="A", month=sample(seq(as.Date("2011/1/1"), as.Date("2012/1/1"), by="month"), nr, replace=T)),
    data.table(type="B", month=sample(seq(as.Date("2011/1/1"), as.Date("2012/1/1"), by="month"), 100*nr, replace=T))
)
plot.dt <- inp.dt[, .(count=.N), .(type,month)]

mnth <- sort(unique(plot.dt[["month"]]))
plot.dt[, ":="(type=factor(type), month=factor(month, label=format(mnth, format="%Y-%b"), ordered=TRUE))]

g <- ggplot(plot.dt, aes(x=month, y=count)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity") + expand_limits(y=0) + facet_grid(type~., scales="free_y")
print(g)
```

If I remove `scales=` the top facet becomes uninteresting.  Is there a way of showing this information as facets (not on separate pages), while still conveying the vast difference in scales.  Eg, how can I set the ymax for the top facet only to a higher number?

Comment: I believe you can do this with `gridExtra`.

Comment: `scales = free` sounds like the appropriate command. If you want control over the limits for a specific panel, you can always add a dummy layer with `geom_blank()`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want the scales set to, so I just picked some numbers arbitrarily.

```
require(data.table)
require(ggplot2)

nr <- 10000
inp.dt <- rbind(
  data.table(type="A", month=sample(seq(as.Date("2011/1/1"), as.Date("2012/1/1"), by="month"), nr, replace=T)),
  data.table(type="B", month=sample(seq(as.Date("2011/1/1"), as.Date("2012/1/1"), by="month"), 100*nr, replace=T))
)
plot.dt <- inp.dt[, .(count=.N), .(type,month)]

mnth <- sort(unique(plot.dt[["month"]]))
plot.dt[, ":="(type=factor(type), month=factor(month, label=format(mnth, format="%Y-%b"), ordered=TRUE))]

# g <- ggplot(plot.dt, aes(x=month, y=count)) + 
#   geom_bar(stat="identity") + expand_limits(y=0) + facet_grid(type~., scales="free_y")
# print(g)

g1 <- ggplot(plot.dt[plot.dt$type=="A",], aes(x=month, y=count)) +  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1500))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + expand_limits(y=0) #+ facet_grid(type~., scales="free_y")
print(g1)

g2 <- ggplot(plot.dt[plot.dt$type=="B",], aes(x=month, y=count)) +   scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,800000))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + expand_limits(y=0) #+ facet_grid(type~., scales="free_y")
print(g2)


install.packages("gridExtra")
library(gridExtra)
gA <- ggplotGrob(g1)
gB <- ggplotGrob(g2)


p <- arrangeGrob(
  gA, gB, nrow = 2, heights = c(0.80, 0.80))

plot(p)
```